# OrientDB and mmap (performance issue)

Tags: performance, orientdb

If I iterate over a cluster, using the following code:

```
for (ODocument document : m_database.browseCluster(clusterName)) {
    // ...
}
```

I observe very poor performance, (ca. 10 records per seconds are fetched), but only if sufficient memory is allocated to Java process. If I restrict memory to 64mb - everything runs very fast.

As I can see from profiler, OFileMMap.map is called VERY often in the case when performance is poor. And channel.map(....) consumes most of the time.

If I disable mmap completely by setting file.mmap.strategy=4 - everything is getting fast, but not as fast, as with mmap and restricted memory allocation.

Any ideas?